# How to give an array more chance based on its length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I had these two `data1` and `data2` arrays which were going to get updated based on the different types of data they received (two different languages here).

After receiving enough data, I wanted my code to use the data inside one of the arrays randomly, but the chance of one getting selected had to change based on the amount of data they had stored. The more the data, the higher the probability.

Answer (score 0):

And here is the answer I came up with:

```
if (
  Math.random() * (data1.length / data2.length + 1) <
  data1.length / data2.length
) {
  mainData = data1;
} else if (
  Math.random() * (data1.length / data2.length + 1) >
  data1.length / data2.length
) {
  mainData = data2;
} else if (data1.length === 0) {
  mainData = data2;
} else if (data2.length === 0) {
  mainData = data2;
} else "ERROR";
```

I'm not sure if this is so simple that no one here has ever asked a similar question or it's actually something but yeah I jut wanted to share it with you.